# Understand pdf structure with flatedecode

Tags: pdf

Good day!

I read documentation on pdf, but I have some global problems.

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

I need xref table from pdf file with Cross-Reference Streams.

This is pdf file
https://ufile.io/q77el

Part of pdf file:
startxref
22827515
%%EOF

This is this part:

```
6628 0 obj
<<
/W [1 4 1]
/Info 1 0 R
/Root 2 0 R
/Size 6629
/Type /XRef
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 3996
/DecodeParms <<
/Columns 6
/Predictor 12
>>
>>
stream
  xÚí]{|ŽåŸç=ïÝf6­LNIŒ³ŒeHŽ;ÙæÜÁ!D¥ƒèWé...
endstream
```

I found this text, use function gzucompress and have this

```
$a = gzuncompress(substr($match[2][0],1,-1));

0200 0000 0000 ff02 0200 0000 0301 02ff
0000 000c 0002 0000 000f 7e00 0201 0000
f176 0102 ff00 0000 c2ff 0201 0000 003e
0202 0000 0000 0001 0200 0000 0000 0102
0000 0000 0001 0200 0000 0000 0102 0000
0000 0001 0200 0000 0000 0102 ff00 000d
3bf8 0201 0000 f3c5 0902 0000 0000 0001
0200 0000 0000 0102 0000 0000 0001 0200
0000 0000 0102 0000 0000 0001 0200 0000
0000 0102 0000 0000 0001 0200 0000 0000
```

[txt file](https://ufile.io/5bofz)

But what this mean?
I see /W [1 4 1] means that i need to split the string into 3 parts : 1 byte 4 bytes 1 byte

02 00000000 00
ff 02020000 00
03 0102ff00 00
00 0c000200 00

But this does not work.
please, tell me what my next step. Thank you!

Comment: You considered **W** but you ignored the **Columns** and **Predictor** values in the **DecodeParms**. Have a look at section 7.4.4.4 "LZW and Flate Predictor Functions" in ISO 32000-1.

Comment: Have you had success decoding the data using the predictor information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer - predictor information.
/Columns 6 - mean that splin on n+1 
/Predictor 12 - mean that this is png algoritm

Comment: To be more precise, the `Predictor` possible values are:

1 = No prediction (the default value),
2 = TIFF Predictor,
10 = PNG prediction (on encoding, PNG None on all rows),
11 = PNG prediction (on encoding, PNG Sub on all rows),
12 = PNG prediction (on encoding, PNG Up on all rows),
13 = PNG prediction (on encoding, PNG Average on all rows),
14 = PNG prediction (on encoding, PNG Paeth on all rows),
15= PNG prediction (on encoding, PNG optimum)

Source: https://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0076.htm